# Increased skew_sortkey upon s3 COPY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table that was created via incremental loads that has a lower skew_sortkey value than when I fully load the table via a s3 copy.  Both tables have the same sort key and identical DDLs, but the skew_sortkey value is 7-8 times higher doing the s3 copy.  Is there a reason for this?  How can I improve (reduce) the skew?

Comment: Are you using Interleaved Sort Keys? They are notoriously hard to satisfy due to the complex way that data is intermixed. [Working with sort keys - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Sorting_data.html) even says "Don't use an interleaved sort key on columns with monotonically increasing attributes, such as identity columns, dates, or timestamps.", which is probably happening when you append more data. You can run `VACUUM REINDEX` to clean it up. Even better would be to avoid using Interleaved Sort Keys.

Comment: There's just one sort key on this table.

Comment: Yes, but is it an Interleaved Sort Key or a Compound Sort Key?

Comment: It's neither an interleaved nor compound sort key in my case.

Comment: This might help: [Sort key skew](https://thedataguy.in/rskit/sortkeyskew#:~:text=Sort%20key%20in%20redshift%20is,first%20column%20will%20be%20considered%29.)